# Help with exporting bookmarks from Chrome

Tags: chrome, web-browser

When I have purchased a new computer in the past, I went to the directory where my bookmarks were stored, copied them to a disk and then imported them via the new computer's browser, duplicating my Favorites List.

I just  bought a new computer and I'm trying to do the same.  I'm using Chrome and I can't find the directory that stores my Favorites. I've searched though the Chrome menu.  I found some instructions for exporting bookmarks but there's no 3-bar icon as described in those instructions.

I even went so far as to bookmark a web page with an absurd name like XYZXYZ and used the search feature to find this file name and hence the bookmark directory.  This has worked in the past when I was using Internet Explorer. No luck with this either.

I really don't want to open every bookmark and manually copy the web address to a Notepad file and then manually import one by one so I'd appreciate any assistance that you can offer.  If this isn't the right forum for this question, please suggest a more appropriate one.  TIA.

EDIT

Per the answer below:

> In Chrome simply go to the URL: chrome://bookmarks/

Does that mean that my bookmarks are stored online? I would have expected them to be stored on my computer.  No?

> ...click on the 3 dots to the top right of the page, you will have a drop down for export bookmarks.

Clicking on the 3 bars does not open the same menu that you displayed.  Perhaps I am on an older version of Chrome?  I certainly never upgraded it.  Regardless, from the choices shown in your displayed menu, I went into Bookmark Manager and then Organize and at the bottom it offers the ability to Export Bookmarks To HTML File.  I did that and I now have a standalone file that is operational.

Will the import feature in Internet Explorer (new computer) recognize this HTML and create an IE list of favorites from it?

Thanks for you reply.  Pardon my low tech awareness :->)

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome simply go to the URL: chrome://bookmarks/ and click on the 3 dots to the top right of the page, you will have a drop down for export bookmarks.

[image]

On a new computer I would expect you to be running Windows 10 which currently has 2 programs for browsing the internet installed by default:

- Legacy Internet Explorer *which by default expects an html file to import bookmarks from:* Get to the import by clicking the star on the top right of the window, then from the drop down select "Import and export...", on the dialog select "Import from a file" then Next and tick Favourites and finally pick out the file:
  [image: IE Getting to Import] [image: IE Import Export Dialog 1] [image: IE Import Dialog 2]
- MicroSoft Edge which the pre-installed version offers you an upgrade but currently allows import from html file: Select the 3 dots on the top right of the window, Favourites, Import. In the dialog from the drop down pick the "Favourites or bookmarks HTML file" option, then select your file.

[image: Edge Import]
[image: Edge What Dlg]
[image: Edge File Pick]

*Note that if you accept the upgrade to the "New Edge" it is actually based on the same engine as Chrome.*

Comment: Due to the space limitation in a comment, please see my edit.

Comment: @BobBaerker: Added import details

Comment: I'm baaaack :) . I moved the newly created HTML to the new Win 10 computer. I can click on one at a time and it opens the web site (old computer bookmark) and I can then bookmark it in IE in  new computer.  However, I'd like to do them en masse but I can't find an IMPORT icon in IE and therefore I don't see the important page that you displayed. The new computer has Microsoft Edge but having never used it, I don't know if it needs to be set up. Let's stick with IE. And again, TIA.

Comment: @BobBaerker: Added how to bulk import for both IE & Updated Edge.